# find and replace - with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, text-processing, gawk

I'm writing a desktop application with Electron and ReactJS that edits CSS files.

I need to scan the CSS looking for a class selector, and then clear the following declaration block and add some new properties.

The tricky part is matching the class in the selector. I need the class to be the actual target (not a parent), but there might be multiple comma-separated selectors, and so I need to check all of them.

For example, 
in this file I'm searching for the containerApp class:

.section-main .section-right , .menu .container-manu , .containerApp .container-nav  { 
         background: black; 
}

.section-main2 .section-left , .menu .container-manu , .section-group-d .containerApp  { 
         background: red; 
}

The first block doesn't match because .containerApp is only mentioned as the parent of the real target, .container-nav. The second block does match, and I would want to remove the background: red; and replace it with something else.
What's the best way to go about doing this CSS matching and rewriting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, `.containerApp` needs to be the last element of a selector. Since the selector ends with a comma, or at the curly braces, you need to use a suitable regular expression:

```
sed '/\.containerApp *[,{]/s/{[^}]*}/{ my new css rules }/' app.css
```

Comment: You right..
I just need to know how to do it...
How to clean everything between the {}
And put new properties. can you please help me?

Comment: @Hananc86 Sorry, I thought you just wanted to delete the whole rule.

Comment: Thank u Very much! its very close to what i need.

the only issue that it works only when the rules are in a single line. in addition can you specify to works only on the first match? . thank you very much! i'm so happy :)

Comment: @Hananc86 Do you mean the first selector in the file to match? Matching a pattern that spans several lines is quite difficult to do in `sed`.

Comment: i don't know why buy sometimes it works and sometimes its not... i'm not sure why. ;/